# Rows data should be existing while adding empty rows to table using Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Basically, I am adding empty rows to table which is working in angular-1.0.1.js but when im using same function using angular-1.2.13.js only 1 row is adding
if i tried to add another row it's not working.

[Link1](http://www.intelligrape.com/blog/2012/09/14/angularjs-adding-items-to-a-javascript-list-and-updating-corresponding-dom-dynamically/)
above example is using angular-1.0.1, 
[Link2](http://jsbin.com/fusapojo/5/edit) this code is using angular-1.2.13 and the row data should be retrieving also like "Link1" code.
I tried to combine both examples [Link3](http://jsbin.com/liyawozu/1/edit) here is solution i got.Can any one tel me how to add multiple rows.

I am new to this and started working on angularjs from past 3 days,
hope I gave an clear explanation.

Comment: It seems to work here perfectly, using Google Chrome

Comment: in the second fiddle you provided, link2, it's using angular 1.2.13 and it seem to work properly.

Comment: check this code http://jsbin.com/liyawozu/1/edit i mix it up 
can u tel me how to multiple rows.
@haki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure why this isn't working with 1.2.13 but either changing the `ng-repeat` to ...

```
fruit in fruits track by $index
```

... or changing both the `ng-click` and the associate function to ...

```
<button ng-click="addFruit(newFruit)">Add</button>

$scope.addFruit=function(newFruit){
  $scope.fruits.push(newFruit);
}
```

... will do the trick.

Comment: it is adding only one row at one time, if we want to add empty rows some how about 4 then it is not working.

Comment: Please have a look at this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qwyszJ?p=preview). Do you get any errors in the console?